# Should I use Channel API or WebRTC?

Tags: google-app-engine

This is a general question regarding on Google app engine platform. I am inspired by Snapchat architecture that there are using Google app engine, that the platform auto-magically scales for them without the need of configuring load balancing and stuff.

So my goal is to build a simple chat platform in Java running on Google App engine but rather confused on which API should I depend on. Channel API or WebRTC API for long time uses.

I read online on what it each API does, but still confused on which one to choose, to power up my future chat platform.